# Как в WPF (C#) добавить консоль

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, консоль

Друг писал на плюсах приложение. Он к WPF'у добавил консоль, которую можно то отображать, то скрывать.

Что-то типа консоли дебага, куда можно свой текст выводить.

Как добавить в .NET Framework 4.8 или .NET 6?

(Для пущей наглядности консоль дебага TLauncher)

Comment: Обычное окно (Window) с TextBox. Можно мимикрировать его под консоль, задав моноширинный шрифт светлого цвета и тёмный фон.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov
 Да, я знаю о таком способе, но хотелось бы именно консоль. Если не получится решить из треда с ответом, тогда сделаю по Вашему совету ;)